# Netbeans: PHP Plugin Installation Error

Tags: php, plugins, netbeans-7

I am using Netbeans 7.1.2 and I am trying to install PHP plugin but getting this error:

> The plugin Editor Library is requested in version >= 2.1 (release
>   version 2) but only 3.17.1.19.25 (of release version different from 2)
>   was found.

I have already installed following plugins:
[image: Installed Plugins]
How can I fix this?

Comment: Download and install the package specific to PHP from http://www.netbeans.com/downloads/index.html

Comment: Which Update centers are you using?

Comment: @JamesCampbell What you mean by invalid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloading and installing Netbeans with only PHP support over existing installation solved the problem as Parahat Melayev suggested in comments.